# Не могу принять данные из нескольких таблиц БД на php

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть страница на котором будет отображаться данные взятые с трех таблиц mysql.
Это для первой (основной)

```
$projects = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `projects` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $projectsArr = Array();
    while($proj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($projects)){
        $projectsArr[] = Array($proj['login'], $proj['title'], $proj['description'], $proj['url'], $proj['poster'], $proj['memory'], $proj['date']);
    }
```

тут немного HTML кода...

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < count($projectsArr); $i++):?>
```

цикл для отображения всех данных с массива. Внутри цикла HTML код и

```
$login_project = $projectsArr[$i][0];
$title_project = $projectsArr[$i][1];
```

$marks = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `projects-mark` WHERE `login-project`='$login_project' AND `title-project` = '$title_project'");

```
while($mark = mysqli_fetch_assoc($marks)){
        $marksArr[] = $mark['mark'];
    }
```

Там где WHERE $login_project и $title_project на втором запросе, они взяты с основной таблицы

```
$comments = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `projects-comment` WHERE `login-project`='$login_project' AND `title-project` = '$title_project' ORDER BY `id` DESC"); 
    $commentsArr = Array();
    while($comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments)){
        $commentsArr[] = Array($comment['login'], $comment['comment'], $comment['date']);
    } 
    for ($i=0; $i < count($commentsArr); $i++):?>

      <div class="comment"> 
        <h2><?php print_r($commentsArr[$i][0]) ?></h2>
        <p><?php print_r($commentsArr[$i][1]) ?></p>
        <p><?php print_r($commentsArr[$i][2]) ?></p>
      </div>
    <?php endfor ?>
```

Это уже третий запрос с циклом для отображения комментариев. И это все в одном большом цикле. Каждый раз когда выполняется цикл отображается другие данные. 2-3 запросе там где where изменяются.

Запросы все работают, проблема в том что отображается только один блок, остальные которые есть в таблице они не отображаются.

Comment: если цикл `<?php for ($i=0; $i < count($commentsArr); $i++):?>` вложен в цикл `<?php for ($i=0; $i < count($projectsArr); $i++):?>`, то переменная `$i` для родительского цикла перезаписывается в дочернем - после первой итерации инкремент родительского цикла достигнет лимита. Почему не `foreach($commentsArr as $comment)`?

Comment: @Gust боюсь проблема не в цикле, я изменил переменную $i результат тот же, и для теста удалил этот цикл, без изменений. Наверное из за запросов так выходит, но не знаю как это исправить.